# Required attribute on property with instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I something similar to the following

```
class EntityNameId
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class OrganizationNameId : EntityNameId
{
}

class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        Organization = new OrganizationNameId();
    }
    OrganizationNameId Organization { get; }
}
```

How can I set the `Required` attribute in `PersonViewModel` for `OrganizationNameId.Id` so that client-side validation will work? I don't want to put it in `OrganizationNameId` or `EntityNameId` because its not always required, but it is required for `PersonViewModel`. I am using MVC 3.

**Edit**: I do not want to add a custom property as described below by Bas. I have a custom partial view for `EntityNameId` that allows for it to be reusable.

Comment: check this this out , i already answered this question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757520/3050647

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a property to PersonViewModel that binds to the organisation property:

```
[Required]
public int OrganizationId {
   get { return Organization.Id; }
   set { Organization.Id = value }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer not to do this as I have a custom partial view that is named `EntityNameId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EntityNameId
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(OrganizationNameIdMetadataType))]
public class OrganizationNameId : EntityNameId
{
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        Organization = new OrganizationNameId();
    }
    public OrganizationNameId Organization { get; private set; }
}

public class OrganizationNameIdMetadataType
{
    [Required]
    public object Id { get; set; }
}
```

[Customizing ASP.NET MVC 2 - Metadata and Validation](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx)

How about use MetadataType attribute?

Comment: I don't want it to be required in all cases.