# How to set metadaType in two class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a class the sales and product, which have the same declaration of object, these two class is auto generated by the server, all i want is set the annotation of them so that it can be reusable all the time, how can i set the MetadataType of this two into one,

From Sales

```
public partial class Sales
{
  public string Currency { get; set;}
}
```

From Product

```
public partial class Product
{
  public string Currency { get; set;}
}


namespace Validation.Access
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TransferModuleValidation))]

    public partial class Product { }

    public partial class TransferModuleValidation
    {
        [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than or 3 characters")]
        public string Currency { get; set; 
    }
}
```

how can i set Sales in that example?
do i have to inherit class (Product) to Sales?

Comment: check this this out , i already answered this question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757520/3050647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the MetadataType to the other class...

```
namespace Validation.Access
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(TransferModuleValidation))]
    public partial class Sales { }

    [MetadataType(typeof(TransferModuleValidation))]
    public partial class Product { }

    public partial class TransferModuleValidation
    {
        [MaxLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than or 3 characters")]
        public string Currency { get; set; 
    }
}
```