# MetadataType attribute removs when edmx change

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

How to prevent removal of `MetadataType` attribute when `edmx` changes. All the time some changes to the `edmx` and save after changes it fill remove all `MetadataType` attributes.

Comment: check this this out , i already answered this question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24757520/3050647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `partial classes` for that.
**Never** modify a `designer` code file, since it's *reproduced from scratch* on every change.

[Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707339%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)